# How to add icons to multi-select?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap's multi-select and i'm trying to add font-awesome icons...i'm using the icons as unicode but it's not working .

```
 <select style="font-family:'FontAwesome', Arial;" multiple="multiple" 
      class="form-control vacances">
  <option>&#xf2bc; 1</option>
  <option>&#xf2bc; 2</option>
  <option>&#xf2bc; 3</option>
</select>
```

I've noticed that the Multi-select constructor is adding it's own ul-li, with it's own template ... so how can i customize it if i want to remove the select options counter - it's messing up the ui 
 [image: Exapmle]

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/mgLyv9an/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the native `<select>` element is hidden, and the "select" you're seeing is just a `<li>` / `<ul>` structure generated by the multi-select plugin, you should apply CSS rules for the `.multiselect-native-select` element (which is a parrent element) instead of the original `<select>`:

```
.multiselect-native-select {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', 'Helvetica';
}
```

This is how the *multi-select* structure looks like:

```
<!-- Apply CSS rules here: -->
<span class="multiselect-native-select">

  <!-- This is your original <select> element, which is hidden: -->
  <select multiple="multiple" class="fontawesome-select vacances">
    <option disabled="" selected="">Options</option>
    <option> ZONE B</option>
    ...
  </select>

  <!-- This is the structure generated by multi-select plugin: -->
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Options" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="multiselect-selected-text">Options</span>
      <b class="caret"></b>
    </button>
    <ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu">

      <li class="disabled active">
        <a tabindex="-1">
          <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Options" disabled=""> Options
          </label>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="disabled active">
        <a tabindex="0">
          <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value=" ZONE B">  ZONE B
          </label>
        </a>
      </li>
      ...

    </ul>
  </div>
</span>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mgLyv9an/3/)

---

To disable options counter, you have to use both, [**`numberDisplayed`**](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-numberDisplayed) and [**`allSelectedText`**](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-allSelectedText) options:

```
$('.vacances').multiselect({
  numberDisplayed: 10, //number that is more or equal to number of options
  allSelectedText: false
});
```

Comment: Thanks - how can i remove the option's counter?

Comment: @RoyBarOn what you mean by *option's counter*?

Comment: When i select  multiple selection - the option's names adds to the the select box - after 4 items are added - it's changing to "all selected(4)"

Answer (score 0):

Html

```html
<select style="font-family:'FontAwesome', Arial;" multiple="multiple" 
          class="form-control vacances" id="opt">
      <option>value1</option>
      <option>value2</option>
      <option>value3</option>
    </select>
```

Css

```css
select#opt option[value="value1"]   { background-image:url(yourIcon.png);   }
select#opt option[value="value2"] { background-image:url(yourIcon.png); }
select#opt option[value="value3"] { background-image:url(yourIcon.png); }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="form-control vacances">
  <option><i class="fa fa-font-icon-name></i> 1</option>
  <option><i class="fa fa-font-icon-name></i> 2</option>
  <option><i class="fa fa-font-icon-name></i> 3</option>
</select>
```

fa class's font-family is "FontAwesome", font-icon-name, please refers to http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/

Seeing your codes on your fiddle, here is a quick fix to override the style

```
.multiselect-container > li > a > label > input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
.multiselect-container > li > a > label {
  padding: 3px 16px;
}
```

First you remove the checkboxes, and the second, you should remove the padding area on the left.